# Modal reopens when dispatching an action React Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, axios, redux-toolkit

just started using React Redux Toolkit with nextjs. I am trying to find a way to submit a form by dispatching a post request action from inside a modal but every time call the dispatch action it reopens it. Is there any other way to properly dispatch the action without reopening the modal.

Help would be very appreciated :)
Thanks a lot!

Here are some parts of my code.

AddressForm.js

```
const handleAddAddress = (data) => {
    const addressForm = JSON.stringify({
      userName: data.userName,
      userAddress: data.userAddress,
      userAddress2: "",
      userCity: data.userCity,
      userPincode: data.userPincode,
      userState: data.userState,
      userEmail: data.userEmail,
      userMobileNumber: data.userMobileNumber,
      isDefault: true,
    });
    dispatch(saveAddress({ addressForm })).unwrap(); **//here I am dispatching the post action **
  };
```

address.slice.js **//this is the slice from where I am calling the api**

```
export const saveAddress = createAsyncThunk(
  "address/saveAddress",
  async ({ addressForm }, { getState, rejectWithValue }) => {
    const state = getState();
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: `${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/api/v1/saveaddress`,
        data: addressForm,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${state.auth.userToken}`,
        },
      });
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (!error.response) {
        throw err;
      }
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);

const addressSlice = createSlice({
  name: "address",
  initialState: {
    addresses: [],
    pincodeState: {},
    httpErr: [],
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [saveAddress.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [saveAddress.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.addresses = action.payload.addresses;
      localStorage.setItem("addresses", JSON.stringify(state.addresses));
    },
    [saveAddress.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.httpErr = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: how `handleAddAddress` is called ? can you provide form's code as well ?